# Como pegar Paramentos de uma URL e colocar em um Botão?

Tags: javascript, html

como fazer uma pagina ser redirecionada para outra usando os paramentros da URL

por exemplo: [www.dominioaqui.com.br/index.html?link=https://www.google.com.br](http://www.dominioaqui.com.br/index.html?link=https://www.google.com.br)

nesse exemplo tenho uma página com um botão que redirecione para o paramentro inserido em "?link="
que seria o Google.

desse jeito posso usar a mesma pagina com varios parametros, sem ter que criar uma pagina diferente para cada link

um código que encontrei, mas tentei usar e não deu certo

Continuar

```
<script>
    var path = location.pathname+location.search;
    var meusiteid  = 'https://www.meusite.com.br' + path;
    document.getElementById('linknaurl').addEventListener('click', function (e) {window.location.replace(meusiteid);});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem muitas maneiras de ler os parametros da url que estão no `location.search`.

Aqui tem várias soluções: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Peguei um exemplo e adaptei a sua pergunta:

```js
function get(query, chave) {
    var half = query.split('&' + chave + '=')[1];
    if (!half) half = query.split('?' + chave + '=')[1];
    return half !== undefined ? decodeURIComponent(half.split('&')[0]) : null;
}


// Usei a variável com um conteúdo para demonstrar sem precisar "vir" de outro link, mas a variável url deve pegar location.search
// var url = window.location.search;
var url = "http://www.dominioaqui.com.br/index.html?link=https://www.google.com.br";

var meusiteid = get(url, "link");

if (meusiteid != null) {
    document.getElementById('linknaurl').addEventListener('click', function (e) {   window.location.replace(meusiteid);});
}
```

```html
<button id="linknaurl">Clique aqui para redirecionar</button>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Para que você possa trabalhar com *querystring* de uma URL, você pode utilizar a interface *URLSearchParams* do javascript.

Vamos supor que você possua a seguinte URL:

```
https://domain.com/?product=pant&color=blue&size=m
```

Para você pegar a *querystring*, faça o seguinte:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString)
// ?product=pant&color=blue&size=m
```

Uma vez tendo o valor da *querystring* em uma constante, instancie um objeto *URLSearchParams*, passando essa constante como parâmetro:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
```

Para pegar um parâmetro em específco, utilize o método *get()*:

```
const product = urlParams.get('product')
console.log(queryString);
// pant
```

Para verificar se um determinado parâmetro existe, utilize o método *has()*, passando o nome desse parâmetro como parâmetro da função:

```
console.log(urlParams.has('color'));
// true
console.log(urlParams.has('quantity'));
// false
```

Caso queira saber mais detalhes sobre essa inteface, clique nesse [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).